# SQL Server 100% CPU when running a Stored Procedure with date filtering

Tags: php, sql-server, datetime, stored-procedures

I have been having this problem for a while now and cannot for the life of me figure out what is causing it so hopefully somebody can help.

This is my stored procedure

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [Report].[Purchasing_PickRateAndSales]
@StartDate nvarchar(50),
@EndDate nvarchar(50),
@Branch nvarchar(50)

AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    SELECT
        ILines.Part,
        Product.[Desc],
        Count(ILines.Qty) AS Frequency,
        Sum(ILines.Qty) AS Quantity,
        Month([ILines].[DateTime]) AS [Month],
        ILines.Branch

    FROM
        Autopart.dbo.ILines
        LEFT JOIN Autopart.dbo.Product ON ILines.Part = Product.KeyCode
        INNER JOIN Autopart.dbo.IHeads ON ILines.Document = IHeads.Document

    WHERE
        (ILines.[DateTime] BETWEEN CONVERT(datetime, @StartDate, 103) AND CONVERT(datetime, @EndDate, 103))

    GROUP BY
        ILines.Part,
        Product.[Desc],
        Month([ILines].[DateTime]),
        ILines.Branch

    HAVING
        (ILines.Branch LIKE @Branch)

    ORDER BY
        ILines.Part,
        Month([ILines].[DateTime])

END
```

Please excuse the nvarchar for the start and end date but for reference i have tried this with datetime as well.

I use PHP with SQLSRV drivers to connect and run the stored procedure, the date is currently being passed as dd/mm/yyyy format but i have tried passing it as datetime using the php function `DateTime::createFromFormat();` with no success

Every time i run a procedure like this it knocks the server to 100% cpu and doesn't ever time out or finish until i stop the query.

To rule out an SQL issue i have manually inserted the parameters into the stored procedure which worked immediately so it makes me think it is a php or driver issue

Let me know if you need any more info

UPDATED:

After viewing the article posted in the comments i found that the parameter sniffing seemed to be the cause of this, i have implemented the following which now runs flawlessly

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [Report].[Purchasing_PickRateAndSales]
@StartDate datetime,
@EndDate datetime,
@Branch nvarchar(50)

AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    DECLARE @SD datetime
    DECLARE @ED datetime

    SET @SD = @StartDate
    SET @ED = @EndDate

    SELECT
        ILines.Part,
        Product.[Desc],
        Count(ILines.Qty) AS Frequency,
        Sum(ILines.Qty) AS Quantity,
        Month([ILines].[DateTime]) AS [Month],
        ILines.Branch

    FROM
        Autopart.dbo.ILines
        LEFT JOIN Autopart.dbo.Product ON ILines.Part = Product.KeyCode
        INNER JOIN Autopart.dbo.IHeads ON ILines.Document = IHeads.Document

    WHERE
        (ILines.[DateTime] BETWEEN @SD AND @ED)

    GROUP BY
        ILines.Part,
        Product.[Desc],
        Month([ILines].[DateTime]),
        ILines.Branch

    HAVING
        (ILines.Branch = @Branch)

    ORDER BY
        ILines.Part,
        Month([ILines].[DateTime])
```

Comment: Can you get rid of the LIKE?  Like tends to be a very "greedy" process.  If you can select a specific branch or group of branches, that would be great.  The other issue I can see if you have a WHERE with a HAVING - this may also impede performance.

Comment: Why are you passing in datetime values as varchars? Why not make your parameter be a datetime?

Comment: @Leptonator the way this is coded it is the same thing as = because there is no wildcard there.

Comment: This is almost certainly an issue with parameter sniffing. Here is an excellent article on the topic. http://sqlinthewild.co.za/index.php/2007/11/27/parameter-sniffing/

Comment: What about using performance Analyzer in SQL Studio?  Where are the huge or pig processes going to?

Comment: I have changed the like to an = which is a fair point, the sql query is converted from an access query. I have changed it back to datetime however i did mention this in my original post that i had tried both ways. I cannot use the performance analyzer as the server is at 100% and never kicks in

Comment: @SeanLange I have read through the article and implemented the inner parameters which seems to have resolved it! Could you post your comment as an answer so i can mark it please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The behavior you are describing sounds like a typical case of parameter sniffing. Especially the part when it runs super fast with the values declared inside the procedure. See this article for a deeper explanation of parameter sniffing. http://sqlinthewild.co.za/index.php/2007/11/27/parameter-sniffing/

Comment: Thanks for your quick and helpful response Sean, i have edited my question with the finished procedure which now works